# onClick events not working on Victory Pie React-Native

Tags: react-native, victory-charts

```
<View
    style={styles.chart}}} >
    <Svg height={400} width={400}>
      <VictoryPie
        colorScale={["#00897B", "#7fc4bd", "#b70104" ]}
        innerRadius={90}
        style={{
          labels: {
            fontSize: 18, fill: "#ffffff"
          }
        }}
        animate={{ duration: 1500 }}
        data={this.state.data}
        padding={{ top: 0, bottom: 35, right:10, left:10 }}
        labelRadius={100}
        standalone={false}
        width={400}
        height={400}
        events={[{
          target: "data",
          eventHandlers: {
            onClick: () => {
              return [
                {
                  target: "data",
                  mutation: (props) => {
                    console.log('index: '+props.index);
                    return null;
                  }
                }, {
                  target: "labels",
                  mutation: (props) => {
                    console.log('text: '+props.text);
                    return null;
                  }
                }
              ];
            }
          }
        }]}/>
      <VictoryLabel
        x={200} y={200}
        textAnchor="middle"
        style={{ fontSize: 23,fill: 'white'}}
        text="Total Revenue"/>
    </Svg>
</View>
```

I used standalone={false} in Victory Pie Because it's under svg as suggested by many in victory chart issues in github but no use it's not firing any events. Its not working both in ios and android. Please help me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i found an answer replace **onClick** in event handlers with **onPressIn**.

Comment: I had the same issue, but with the Victory Bar, and this answer did the trick. Thanks!

Comment: it is also `onPress` event

Answer (score 3):

```
    <VictoryPie
          data={array}
          width={350}
          height={350}
          innerRadius={95}
          colorScale={["#00897B", "#7fc4bd", "#b70104" ]}
          events={[
            {
              target: 'data',
              eventHandlers: {
                onPressIn: () => {
                  return [
                    {
                      target: 'data',
                      mutation: dataProps => {
                          console.log('item selected is',dataProps.index)
                            return {}
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                },
                onPressOut: () => {
                }
              }
            }
          ]}
     />
```